# Getting Error while performing Login

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, odbc

i got a problem here,im trying to run my crystal report on server that running windows server 2008 R2 64-bit..when i run my crystal report on dev machine everything is running fine but when i deploy on server it give me this error:

> Logon failed. Details: IM002:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
>   source name not found and no default driver specified Error in File
>   C:\Windows\TEMP\monthlysalereport
>   {4E4A28D4-6F73-48A7-8DF5-D44071205D17}.rpt: Unable to connect:
>   incorrect log on parameters.

i already troubleshoot this problem with set on my server C:\Windows\SysWOW64 set my system DSN and it gave me the same error.i try to connect my database on Microsoft SQL Server on the server
i already Google this problem and stuck for two days.
i hope somebody can help me with this problem..
sorry for bad English.

Comment: Sounds like a installation issue. Do you have correct crystal runtime installed on server? Also check the database drivers you are using you are using on the report.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem.the problem is name in system DSN cannot have space and same with the dev machine..